# how to parse xml-file in vb6 recursive

Tags: xml, vb6, ixmldomnode

I'm new to vb6 and have to parse an xml document with a different depth of the tags like to following example:

```
<start>
  <b>text1</b>
  <c>
    <c1>
      <d>text</d>
    </c1>
  </c>
</start>
```

I'm using MSXML and trying to solve this problem recursive. My code is:

```
Sub1()
  Set objXML = CreateObject("Msxml.DOMDocument")
  objXML.async = True
  objXML.Load "text.xml"

  Dim nodeList As IXMLDOMNodeList
  Dim node As IXMLDOMNode

  Set nodeList = objXML.selectNodes("*")

  For Each node In nodeList
    print node.nodeName  ' this works'
    printNode (node)     'here is the problem explained below'
  Next node
End Sub


Sub printNode(node As IXMLDOMNode)
  Dim xmlNode As IXMLDOMNode
  If node.hasChildNodes Then
    For Each xmlNode In node.childNodes
      printNode (xmlNode)
    Next xmlNode
    Print node.nodeName
  End If 
End Sub
```

The problem is that it isn't possible to call the *sub printNode* with the parameter *node* of the type *IXmlDomNode*. When I try to run the program I always get a *runtimeerror 438* which says *object doesn't support this function*

The node does exist, I have tested this and can print the name and value of the node.

Can anyone explain my why and give me a hint how/solution how I can solve this problem?

Comment: You are not parsing anything.  You already asked MSXML to do the parsing.  What you seem to be struggling with is traversing the DOM.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for correcting me, my discription was not completely correct at this point. The problem was in traversing the DOM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your code. If you are calling a Sub you either do so without enclosing the parameters in parenthesis, or you use the Call Keyword in front of the Sub name.

```
Public Sub Sub1()
    Set objXML = CreateObject("Msxml.DOMDocument")
    objXML.async = True
    objXML.Load "text.xml"

    Dim nodeList As IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim node As IXMLDOMNode

    Set nodeList = objXML.selectNodes("*")

    For Each node In nodeList
        print node.nodeName  ' this works'
        Call printNode(node)     'here is the problem explained below'
    Next node
End Sub

Public Sub printNode(node As IXMLDOMNode)
    Dim xmlNode As IXMLDOMNode

    If node.hasChildNodes Then
        For Each xmlNode In node.childNodes
            Call printNode(xmlNode)
        Next xmlNode
        Print node.nodeName
    End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, if you know this it is quite easy. Do you know why there are two ways (with paranthesis and without them) to call a **sub** in vb6? This is quite unusual when you come from an language like **java**

Comment: I don't, but I would guess it can be traced back to the language origin. Visual Basic has always had some of the original language features that remained in for backward compatibility.